# clang O3/O2 error for Linpack with NEON instructions

Tags: c, arm, clang

I am using code Neonlinpack code from,
[http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/Raspberry_Pi_Benchmarks.zip][1]

When I compile it with clang without any optimization flags, it runs OK. But when I use O3/O2 flags in command,

```
clang -target armv7a-linux-gnueabihf -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard linpackneon.c cpuidc.c -O3 -o linpackneon
```

I get the following errors

```
In file included from cpuidc.c:13:
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:426:
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:756:25: error: invalid output constraint '=&q' in
      asm
                    : "=t" (__value), "=&q" (__ignore), "=m" (__cwtmp),       \
                                      ^
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:756:25: error: invalid output constraint '=&q' in
      asm
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:756:25: error: invalid output constraint '=&q' in
      asm
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:774:25: error: invalid output constraint '=&q' in
      asm
                    : "=t" (__value), "=&q" (__ignore), "=m" (__cwtmp),       \
                                      ^
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:774:25: error: invalid output constraint '=&q' in
      asm
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:774:25: error: invalid output constraint '=&q' in
      asm
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:881:3: error: unknown register name 'st' in asm
  __lrint_code;
  ^
/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h:876:40: note: expanded from macro '__lrint_code'
     : "=m" (__lrintres) : "t" (__x) : "st");
```

What is the reason behind these errors. I do not encounter such errors with GCC.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @FUZxxl I have edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All cpuid.c does is obtain time/timing and configuration details from Linux. Either compile it separately with no optimisation or comment out statements as appropriate. Only timing data is needed.

Comment: I have done this but still linpackneon.c also has math.h at line 69 which is giving the same error with O2 and O3 in clang.

Comment: with armclang compiler (built in DS-5) i am facing the same error. Only gcc does not give error here.